# Does Ubuntu work with Wacom's wireless acessory kit (intuos5)

Tags: wireless, compatibility, wacom

I'm interested on getting a wacom Intuos5 and, while I know that it works fine using usb, I was wondering if anyone has any experience with it using the wireless kit. I've tried to search but couldn't find a straight answer to this.

So, does the Intuos5 with the wireless kit work on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got my Intuos5 working over USB and Wifi.

Just as simple as building the drivers *[Xf86-input-wacom](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/?title=Xf86-input-wacom)* and *[Input-wacom](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Input-wacom)* straight from *git*.

Got first the Error message  "*ltmain.sh not found*" when running `./autogen.sh` for the *Input-wacom* driver. There is a workaround [here](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.wacom/page=6)

**The remaining problem: touch ring and pad buttons are not working yet.**

Comment: This was 3 years ago, does it Just Work now without building drivers from git?

Answer (score 1):

I got the Wacom Intuos5 and tried to get it to work over USB and wireless without success -
even though *dmesg* shoes that the Wacom device has been connected. Previously I worked with a Cintiq UX21 on the same system, which worked right out of the box. 
I hope the Intuos5 will work after the 13.10 upgrade.